# Error causing File Content to become multiplied

Tags: python, bigdata

I am trying to get the data like the following, but I am getting a logical error which acts as multiplying `content * 2`, however, I cannot see the error clearly. my dict content is the following format. what am I doing wrong at the moment to get the data?

AU dict

```
Melbourne
Canberra
Sydney
Hobart
Brisbane
```

companies

```
4INFO
Adbot
Adform
Adobe Systems
ADTECH
Adtile Technologies
Afilias
Alawar Entertainment
Amazon.com
AppNexus
Badgeville
BrightRoll
comScore
```

```
countries = {
      'AU': open('AU','r').read().splitlines(),
      'BE': open('BE','r').read().splitlines(),
      'CA': open('CA','r').read().splitlines(),
      'CH': open('CH','r').read().splitlines(),
      'CZ': open('CZ','r').read().splitlines(),
      'DE': open('DE','r').read().splitlines(),
      'ES': open('ES','r').read().splitlines(),
      'FR': open('FR','r').read().splitlines(),
      'GB': open('GB','r').read().splitlines(),
      'IE': open('IE','r').read().splitlines(),
      'IT': open('IT','r').read().splitlines(),
      'MX': open('MX','r').read().splitlines(),
      'NL': open('NL','r').read().splitlines(),
      'NZ': open('NZ','r').read().splitlines(),
      'PL': open('PL','r').read().splitlines(),
      'RO': open('RO','r').read().splitlines(),
      'RU': open('RU','r').read().splitlines(),
      'SE': open('SE','r').read().splitlines(),
      'SG': open('SG','r').read().splitlines(),
      'US': open('US','r').read().splitlines(),   
}

companies = open('companies.txt','r').read().splitlines()
jobs = ['business+analyst','data+scientist']

for company in companies:
      for country in countries:
            for i in countries[country]:
                  for job in jobs:
                        tail = ""
                        print("using {} {}{}".format(country, company, tail))
```

output

```
using AU 0
using AU 0
using AU 0
using AU 0
using AU 0
using AU 0
using AU 0
using AU 0
using AU 0
using AU 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
```

I expect the output of my current output to be,

```
using AU 0
using AU 0
using AU 0
using AU 0
using AU 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
using BE 0
```

Comment: ’for job in jobs’ seems to be useless loop which duplicates your output as jobs has 2 items.

Comment: how can I fix it? I need to complete my string as `company country city job` considering, `jobs` will be an array of given roles may be a filename which contains all roles

Comment: You didn't provide test data. What is the content of `companies.txt`? Assumming we only care about AU and BE, what is the content of these files? What do you want to achieve? In your question you wrote you wanted 2 times less output, now you write someting about creating string with 4 different values. You need to be specific and provide all data.

Comment: I updated the post. I also added the `AU` contents , and `company`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you wrote you want to print `company country city job`.

Looking at `AU dict` there seems to be a list of cities, then your loop `for i in countries[country]:` lists cities. Simply printing `company country city job` can be achieved using what you already have:

```
for company in companies:
    for country in countries:
        for city in countries[country]: # i renamed to city for better readability
            for job in jobs:
                print("{} {} {} {}".format(company, country, city, job))
```